# My UWP app crashes on Faulting Module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Tags: uwp, crash, windows-10

My UWP application crashed with no exceptions.
Event Log:
Windows OS Name: MicroSoft Windows 10 Pro
Version: 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Faulting application name: App.Name, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5e5883fd
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.19041.3693, time stamp: 0x4d0a8551
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000014eb49
Faulting process id: 0x259c
Faulting application start time: 0x01da196718830019
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\App\App.name
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 47086d13-72cf-43b7-b2e0-4c730e9cc6ed
Faulting package full name: App.Name
Faulting package-relative application ID: App

This application was running for more than 5 days and it crashed.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: I also have started having this issue, first it was crashing on Windows.UI.Xaml.dll and now it is crashing on gdi32full.dll. It's hard to debug because it only seems to be happening on builds uploaded to the Store and it crashes before any logging is triggered.